# Comparing results from two different tables

Tags: php, mysql

Ok...

So lets say I have one DB called "system"

In system I have 2 tables

One is called "names" and the other is called "username"

Now,  I have a spot where it displays information from the table "name"

before it displays though, I want it to check if the name from the table "name" matches the one of the names in the other table "username"

If it does I want it to display the information from the table "username"

I am pretty good at php, just don't know how to go about comparing different table information.

Comment: `if ($valueFromTable1 == $valueFromTable2)` ?

Comment: @Kevin1990 Please post the schema of both tables and explain exactly what result you want to get with an example. Most likely what you are looking for is called an SQL JOIN, but your question is too vague for a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
SELECT un.* FROM usernames un INNER JOIN names n ON n.name=un.name
```